# How to achieve simple OOP in Solidity?

Tags: oop, ethereum, solidity

**Code:**

```
contract A
{
    uint public foo;

    function A(uint _foo)
    {
        foo = _foo;
    }
}

contract B
{
    uint bar;

    function B()
    {
        A a = new A(42);
        bar = a.foo;
    }
}
```

**Compile Error**

```
Test:18:15: Error: Type function () returns (uint256) is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256.
        bar = a.foo;
              ^---^
```

How can I read public variables of a contract in another?

Comment: FYI, there is also [ethereum.stackexchange.com](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/) if you have any specific questions regarding ethereum, solidity, smart contracts and dapp development.

Comment: thanks, yeah, I might end up over there ...

Answer (score 3):

```
contract A
{
    uint public foo;

    function A(uint _foo)
    {
        foo = _foo;
    }
}

contract B
{
    uint bar;

    function B()
    {
        A a = new A(42);
        bar = a.foo();
    }
}
```

`bar = a.foo();` instead of `bar = a.foo;` ...